# log4j db apender - log event type in db

Tags: java, log4j

i am using log4j2 in my java web app.

I have it configured to store log info in the database, to be latter used for reporting.

I would like to store in a column of the log table the type of event this log was generated for. These are application events like login/logout/change password/delete record etc.

I though of having a separate table in the db for each type of event, and having a separate logger/appender  for each, but that makes it cumbersome.

Is there a standard way to deal with this kind of situations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to create an `EventLoggingService` which has methods (or builders) to add specific events to the database. You can add a single logger in there to also log the events to the log appenders if you want.

This way, you can make sure that the service has all necessary information before it writes the event into the database. It's also easy to test and use and you can use you IDE to find all places where events are logged.

Another solution is to create a global logger (i.e. a `public static final Logger ... "EventLogger"`) which you can then use in many places to log events. This is easier to setup, avoids duplication if you already have an appender which writes to the database but makes it harder to extract the event details (like type and attributes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i though of that, as i am using ThreadContext for things like username, ip etc. The examples i have seen, set THreadContext values in the filters. I don't know if it is considered a good practice to use it directly in the code (in this case in the managed bean, as i am using JSF), because it is not always easy to know the event type directly in the filter

Comment: Why do you want to log events to the database?

Comment: I need to generate reports on these data, and make theme available via web interface.For the current situation, using other apps/products to manage logs etc is not an option, i need to develop these reports myself using jasper.

Comment: I think I understand now. Please see my new answer.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i would like to do this with log4j2 , if at all possible, before implementing a service that writes to DB. Log4j2 has also option to write logs asynchronously, ThreadContext etc. These and other features make me think twice before developing my own service for the logs. The problem is that i need to have the event type in a way that can be used to map it to a column of the log table, so i would need it to be usable/accessible by the logj2 config file.

Comment: The ThreadContext idea is nearer to what i need, do you see any problems in using it in managedBeans?

Comment: We tried this but it caused subtle problems when we changed the information being logged (some places where such events were logged were missed, then the parser which examined the log message often broke after changes).